# How can I label or tick in pandas for my data sets?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Below is my data-set, I am unable to tick or label [City 1, City 2, City 3  & City 4] in x-axis for the bar graph. Its a 1*4 matrix.

```
City1    City2    City3    City4
1000     1020     940      720
```

Here is my code,

```
df.plot.bar(color = 'deepbluesky', width = 2)
plt.xticks([], rotation = 'vertical')
```

A help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What neither of the answers explain, is that your data needs to be in a long (tidy) format, opposed to a wide format. This can be accomplished with [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) or [`.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try make the Cities and corresponding values appear in columns by stacking. Then set Cities as index. The index is by default forced to plot on the x axis.

Edited as suggested by @Trenton McKinney

```
df.T.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: What you've done, it's redundant to use `.T`. `df.T.plot.bar()` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say my dataset

[image: Dataset]

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
x = df["Position"]
y = df["Salary"]
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.title("Position vs Salary")
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.xlabel("Positions")
plt.ylabel("Salary")
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I was trying to plot when datasets are in horizontal manner. I thought of indexing but never really succeeded. Anyways I got my desired result